# updating listbox from datasource in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a listbox in my form that automatically fills the information from the datasource. I then open a second form to add/remove people from the dataset. when I save and close it, the update is done in the dataset itself but not on the listbox. I added in a button to try to refresh it and I haven't been having any luck.. here is an example of the things ive tried.

```
       Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox1.ValueMember = Nothing
    'ClientInfoTableAdapter.Update(DaycareDataSet2)
    'ListBox1.DataBindings.Clear()
    'ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    '' ClientInfoTableAdapter.Fill(DaycareDataSet2.ClientInfo)
    ListBox1.DataSource = DaycareDataSet2.ClientInfo
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ClientFullName"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "id"
    'ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    listbox1.update()


End Sub
```

Comment: The DataSet cant/wont watch the DB for changes.  If you fill a DataTable (not sure what type `ClientInfo` is) and make changes to *that*, the changes will show up automatically.  It would mean passing info back tot he first form so it can update the DataTable and use the same DatAdapter to perform the update

Comment: I'm using the same dataadapter.. still not working.. any more suggestions? :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I seem to have written a small sub to refresh the data. From what I understand.. my list finally updates now..

```
Public Sub RefreshDatabase()  
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ClientInfo ORDER BY ID", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    Me.listboxClients.DataSource = dt
    Me.listboxClients.DisplayMember = "ClientFullName"
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```